# Using HttpClient with some slashes escaped and some not

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I need to grab the json from a url in c#. The issue is that some of the slashes are escaped and some are not. This is required by couchbase. I can't work out how to do this.

url: http://10.0.0.4:8091/pools/default/buckets/default/stats/replications%2Ff4268e62702130298bf87f17cc481219%2Fdefault%2Fhub%2Fdocs_failed_cr_source

couchbase docs:
http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/rest-api/rest-xdcr-statistics.html

my code:

```
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password) })
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(query);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var info = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return info;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: i think it is worth decoding you url first

Comment: What do you mean by `some of the slashes are escaped and some are not`? Can you give a clear example? Also what is the error you are getting? Like Http 400?